# how to distinct value after query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct, aggregation, cardinality

I use elasticsearch like :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": "my title"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_title": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i just want to sql

```
select distinct title from table where title like '%my title%'
```

the result give me multiple same results, "cardinality" dont worked whit "query"

if you dont understand me, Please forgive my poor English ^_^

Answer (score 1):

[Cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) calculates the **count of distinct values** for a field.

Hence the equivalent sql query for the elasticsearch query you wrote would look like:

```
select count(distinct title) from table where title like '%my title%'
```

What you need to use is the [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for getting the distinct titles.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": "my title"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you need to look into the "aggregations" section of the search response to get the distinct values in the "buckets" array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get expected result:

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
"from": 0,
"size": 200,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "query": {
                        "wildcard": {
                            "title": "*my title*"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"_source": {
    "includes": [
        "title"
    ],
    "excludes": []
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer

but the results still has same value